# My user redirected to System32\config\systemprofile, how to solve it?

Tags: windows-7

My problem is: I have an user on my laptop named alfa. That is the administrator profile.

Well, about a few days ago I "lost" everything. Somehow windows redirected user prefences to

> System32\config\systemprofile

. But my user data is here:

> c:\users\alfa

How can I redirect it to the default, where my user data is. I have already redirected the documents, desktop, etc... But there may something like appdata and you know I want to get my background back and my old startmenu, etc.

How can i do it?

Comment: This happened on my Vista Laptop and my Win7 desktop.  Microsoft screwed up something or there is a nasty malware/virus out there

Comment: I had the same problem. None of the suggestions here helped. I ended up doing system restore to earlier date and that solved it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/changing-profile-from-windows-registry/

> Log into the system with local administrative rights, open RegEdit, and go to:
>
> `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
>
> You will see SID on the left pane and when you select each SID, you will see the profile path for each user that has logged into the system.

Find the profile with the string value `ProfileImagePath` containing path to

```
System32\config\systemprofile
```

and change it back to

```
c:\users\alfa
```

Be sure not to change the system account (should be the first key on the list).

Comment: There is only one with "System32\config\systemprofile" there. And I found the c:\users\alfa record too. It seems the registry key is fine, but than what is wrong?

Comment: go to Computer Management (or run compmgmt.msc by pressing windows key + r) -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> right click "alfa" -> Properties -> "Member Of" tab to see what groups you belong to. Also check the Profile tab to see if there is any irregularity.

Comment: Not sure what happened but I have now seen this on a Vista computer of mine and my dads windows 7.  Is this due to a virus or a windows update that screwed up the users.

Comment: @PuiHoLam Should the Profile tab be blank?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, besides 3 system profiles in `HKLM\software\microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\`.

I found two user profiles with identical names, but one of them with ".bak" in the end. i.e. `S-1-5-21-12345-54321-1000` and `S-1-5-21-12345-54321-1000.bak`.

What I did:

1. Identify which "ProfileImagePath" was the right one: the first one was "C:\Users\TEMP" (TEMP is the name of temporary created user which was deleted some time ago) and the second one was the right one
2. I renamed the first one (without .bak) in "S-1-5-21-12345-54321-1000.old", and deleted ".bak" from the name of the second one
3. I rebooted and it worked

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Thank you for posting your answer -- it's a bit hard to read, though; perhaps consider breaking it up into a bulleted list, or similar.  Instructions for Markdown formatting on the site can be found [here](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Awesome answer! @hBy2Py I have improved readibility of the answer.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after an update. Found 2 problems which resolved it when fixed.

The first problem was related to [Vortexo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/848593/86828). The value was slightly different.

Second problem was under Environment Variables. Processor Architecture was set to amd but my processor is intel. [processor architecture enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.processorarchitecture(v=vs.110).aspx)

To view environment variables press 'windows key' + 'pause" to bring up system information, then go to advanced system settings, then on advanced tab, environment variables is at the bottom.

Fixed it for me, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: AMD64 is the correct value for all 64 bit PC processors. There is no value for Intel made CPUs. The _IA64_ setting is for Itanium processors (no one has them in a PC).

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be that the Explorer is running as `system`. Run Task manager and verify if you have two `explorer.exe` running. If you do, one will be for your original profile and the other for `system`.

End Task both processes and Start a New Task = `explorer.exe`. This should show your original desktop, but you will need to reboot for all settings to take affect. Now, if you reboot and the issue repeats itself, do the process over and then open regedit and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and change the value for Userinit to `C:\Windows\System32\userinit.exe`, then reboot. The value that may be there is `C:\Windows\System32\KUsrInit.exe`. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's weird.  I only have one explorer.exe, with my username attached.  If i kill it and start explorer again, i still have the systemprofile desktop.  But if i click "Show processes from all users" and *then* kill explorer and restart it, i get my correct desktop.  But it doesn't stay through a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

fix/workaround create a new admin user account.

name a new folder on the desktop of the new account and right click properties.
the location of your folder should be C:\Users\username\Desktop if it is you fixed it you just need to 
copy all of your stuff over manually to your new user.
copy from  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile 
to C:\Users\username\

then when you have everything from you old account you can delete it 
remember you might need to backup your passwords/bookmarks from your browser

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and logging back in worked for me.

Comment: A restart fixed it for me as well (but on Windows 8.1)

Answer (score -3):

Try using Microsoft Fixit: It "might" fix most errors, registries.It's a solution center which can fix your errors and files that have been erased and implement it back to its default state.

It can also solve all the performance issues or all the privacy and files that you have partitioned or deleted.

Also works with user accounts. So if you have lost all your user credentials or moved it somewhere else, it can be brought back to its default state

Please try: `http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/`

Don't forget to restart your computer after everything is done.

FYI: you can also download the software and make it "RUN" in your computer it will fix all of your errors and all the faulty files and Windows errors. Including your whole windows Folder.